# Fastest way to generate a non-sequential, integers-only UUID with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, uuid

I'm trying to generate **non-sequential**, **integers-only** UUIDs using MySQL, with the best performance possible.

I know MySQL already offers various ways to generate a reliable UUID:

- [UUID v4](https://www.uuidtools.com/uuid-versions-explained): Great uniqueness but [slow](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/11/22/uuids-are-popular-but-bad-for-performance-lets-discuss/) and stored as UUID type
- [UUID v1](https://www.uuidtools.com/uuid-versions-explained): Similar, but can be sequential, slightly improving indexing performance
- [UUID_SHORT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short): Best performance, shorter, stored on a 64bits BIG INT, but sequential

However, none of these solutions is offering both non-sequential (it will be publicly displayed and I don't want users to be able to track the growth/increment) **and** integers-only UUIDs (for performance).

Using RAND() is out of the question, as collisions are too high, even for < 100K records.

Any smart solution besides converting UUID_V1 to decimal?

Comment: RAND() is not collision-safe.

Comment: @Simulant, Are you suggesting 2^32 would not be enough for 1M records?

Comment: I think he's saying there is a chance, albeit a small one, that 2 of the same id could be randomly generated. If all else fails, you could generate a normal GUID, remove the `-` characters, and use `CONV` to convert it from base 16 to base 10. This will give you a 20 digit number.

Comment: @Simulant even uuids are not guaranteed to avoid collision. It's acceptable because the chance of collision is so remote it's accepted that it will "never" happen.

Comment: @Bruno using 2^32 uuids for 1M records you're *guaranteed* to get a collision. At around 70K rows, there's a 50% change that two will have the same uuid. See [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for why that is so. You need a 64-bit uuid minimum, 128bit would be better.

Comment: Are you wanting a string in the form `nnnnnnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnnnnnnnnn` where `n` are digits (not alpha hex chars)? Or is `nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn` OK?

Comment: @Bohemian - I'm not sure about that.  `RAND()` (in MySQL) seems to be a simple linear congruential generator.  It repeats after 2^30 iterations without any dups meanwhile.  However, multiplying by something or extracting parts of are likely to lead to dups.  Existing UUID algorithms, of which there are several. can virtually guarantee no dups.  They uses parts of the time, etc.  MySQL uses "Type 1", which is composted mostly of a precise clock.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque - You can shuffle the bits of `UUID_V1` to make them approximately sequential.  MySQL 8 and MariaDB 10.7 have functions to assist with that.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque Why exactly are "normal" UUIDs not an option for you? What performance problems are you talking about (where and when)? Why do the UUID must have only digits? Why does it have to be non-sequential. Please [edit] your question to answer these questions and include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do and what restrictions you want to place on the value you want to calculate/generate.

Comment: @Bohemian, Thanks for sharing, very insightful. I just did a quick POC, and actually even with 20K records, I start seeing collisions! I'll update my question.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque You haven't explained in detail what performance issues you have with normal UUIDs in your application. Also please explain what you are trying to do with the generated number/id.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is first a mathematics problem, then a programming problem.

I would consider the simple:  `M = (M + N) % (2^32)` to get the "next" value of `M`.

Where N is a big, positive, odd, integer.

M is the "next" number to use.  (It can be initialized with anything you like).

It will generate 2^32 distinct numbers, then repeat.

2^32 could be any power of 2.  Actually, the critical thing is that 2^32 and N have no factors (other than `1`) in common.

Be careful with `%`; the language you are using may be using 32-bit signed numbers.  Or maybe 64-bit.  In most languages of today 2^16 will work.  But it limits you to 65536 values.

`% 2^P` can also be done using bit masking.

Rand() repeats after only 2^30 values, but `RAND() * 99999` is likely to have some dups in the first 99999 iterations.  There are random number generators that last longer.

1M values is about 20 bits.  So 2^20 works.  Or masking with `& 0xFFFFF`.

If you also convert to hex, then all codes can be 5 characters.  `TO_BASE64()` would compress it to 4 characters.